# When trying to incorporate Google Maps/Bing Maps into an Access From using web browser control, the map doesn't load

Tags: forms, api, google-maps, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to incorporate Google Maps into my Access form so that for every record a map of its address can be shown. Using this video:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHoy6hsAltc
```

for guidance I attempted this except I used Bing Maps. I did exactly as the video did but where the video shows the map, my window is essentially the Bing Search menu with the address typed in but there is only a white screen where the map is.

When trying to add Google Maps to my form I had similar results. Yesterday when I tried it, the usual google maps window came up, but the map box was instead a grey-filled box with nothing in it. I've been trying it today and instead of a grey-filled box, the map box is now white and the usual message "Loading" appears in a yellow box. However this "Loading" box remains on screen indefinitely and the white box never loads.

I've looked online to find an answer, the closest I've found were a couple of posts mentioning the grey-box when trying to implement Google Maps, but I haven't been able to find a solution. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help point me in the direction of the reason this problem is occuring.

EDIT: here's the URL I'm using for Bing Maps:

```
="bing.com/maps/default.aspx?setmkt=en-CA&where1=" & [sAddress]
```

where sAddress is a textbox on the form where the address comes from

EDIT 2: here's a screenshot of what's happening on my screen if it helps:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmiaF.jpg]

Comment: Would you kindly post the code you are using to load the URL into the WebBrowser control?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Sure thing, here's the URL I'm using for the Bing Maps: 

    ="http://www.bing.com/maps/default.aspx?setmkt=en-CA&where1=" & [sAddress]
    
(I have a textbox called sAddress where the user inputs their address)

Comment: Thank you, but you should update your question, not add this as a comment. Also, can you post a sample address you are using so I can test?

Comment: Sorry about that, I just updated it. Here's a sample address: 

1812 Vedder Way, Abbotsford, BC ;

It points to a place in BC, beside the marker you should be able to see a Wal-Mart.

Comment: Have you tried formatting your URL like this: `http://www.bing.com/maps/default.aspx?setmkt=en-CA&where1=1812+Vedder+Way,+Abbotsford,+BC`

Comment: I don't think the problem has so much to do with the URL itself, because the original URL does work if I try it on a regular browser. It just doesn't work when I try to open it through Access. I tried your method in case and it doesn't seem to work. But thanks for trying.

Answer (score 2):

The new web browser control works like any other bound control. Text box, or combo box or whatever. (So a valid expression for a text box is ="abc", but not abc or "abc".)

Your expression I think required the "www" part. The following expression works for me:

`="http://www.bing.com/maps/default.aspx?setmkt=en-CA&where1=" & [Address]`

Comment: Thanks for your response! That's strange, I tried this and nothing changed. If it helps, here's a screenshot I took of what's happening on my screen:

http://i.imgur.com/bDHCm.jpg.

Also, I'm not sure if this changes anything, but I'm using Access 2010 on Windows XP. I don't think that would impact anything but I'm trying what worked for other people on other forums but I'm not finding the same success so maybe it's something small that I'm overlooking to mention.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Function OpenMap(Address, City, State, Zip, Country)

```
Dim strAddress As String
strAddress = Nz(Address)
strAddress = strAddress & IIf(strAddress = "", "", ", ") & Nz(City)
strAddress = strAddress & IIf(strAddress = "", "", ", ") & Nz(State)
strAddress = strAddress & IIf(strAddress = "", "", ", ") & Nz(Zip)
strAddress = strAddress & IIf(strAddress = "", "", ", ") & Nz(Country)
'Debug.Print strAddress

If strAddress = "" Then
    MsgBox "There is no address to map."
Else
    'Application.FollowHyperlink "http://www.bing.com/maps/default.aspx?q=" & strAddress
    Application.FollowHyperlink ("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=" & strAddress)
End If
```

End Function

**I call this function from a form in a button called "cmdOpenMap"
BTW, I recently switched to Google Maps instead of Bing as I found the results were better.**

Private Sub cmdOpenMap_Click()
OpenMap [Address], [City], [Prov], [PostalCode], "Canada"
End Sub